# How to decode that Pokemon puzzle?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

After beating the Elite 4 in LeafGreen and catch 60 Pokemon, you can go to talk to the Team Rocket members just before Mt. Ember. So inside there there are some things (I first thought it was just like the displays they have in museum), who say something. Every one contains one or more 3x3 matrices, where some cells are bolded (I will use * for them).

[image]

I will write every one from top left to bottom right:

```
*+ *+ **   |   ** *+ **      |   ++
++ *+ ++   |   +* +* *+      |   ** 
++ ++ ++   |   ++ ++ ++      |   +*
--------------------------------------
** *+ +*   |   +* *+ *+      |   ++
** ** *+   |   ** ++ *+      |   *+ 
++ ++ ++   |   ++ *+ *+      |   ++
--------------------------------------
** ** *+   |   ** ** *+ +*   |  
++ +* +*   |   *+ ** ** *+   |  
*+ *+ *+   |   *+ *+ *+ *+   |   
--------------------------------------
+* *+ *+   |   +* ** ** *+   |   
** ++ *+   |   ** ++ +* +*   |   
*+ ** **   |   +* ** ** **   |   
--------------------------------------
```

and then in the top room we have 8 messages:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

4)

[image]

5)

[image]

6)

[image]

7)

[image]

8)

[image]

After searching the Internet both with Yahoo! and Google search, I found the meaning, but not the methodology. I don't have an Alakazam in my party, that's why I am asking you experts, how to crack that code?

---

PS - If this is something really trivial in newer generations, excuse me, but I am a guy of the 251 Pokemon.

Comment: This is pure, standard Braille -- there are tons of decoding guides for it online. I believe that the very first Braille message that the player encounters in FireRed/LeafGreen consists of the alphabet followed by a period and a comma -- is this it?

Comment: @A.Mirabeau: Yep, that's it.

Comment: What is a Braille? Ανάγλυφη γραφή τυφλών! Arhg, it's for the blind people, not for the stupid ones, like me, thanks @A.Mirabeau!

Comment: +1 simply for all the work that must've gone into making this question.

Comment: @Deusovi and the checking!! :) Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Braille, the dotted code used for the blind:

[image]

The first message reads:

```
ABC DEF  .
GHI JKL  ,
MNO PQRS
TUV WXYZ
```

The next messages read:

EVERYTHING
HAS MEANING
EXISTENCE
HAS MEANING
BEING ALIVE
HAS MEANING
HAVE DREAMS
USE POWER.

You can find more information about Braille on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille), or on its use in the Pokémon games on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Braille#Inscriptions_in_the_Sevii_Islands).

Comment: If I were you I would hide the meaning in `>!`.

Comment: @gsamaras: There's no need. Spoilers still aren't required here, and typically we only use them for solutions to puzzles posed here rather than questions *about* puzzles. I appreciate the recommendation though!